# mobi.monaca.plugins.MonacaBackend not included in the custom monaca debugger

Tags: cordova, monaca

I am getting the error "The following plugins are not included in the debugger." The plugin name is "mobi.monaca.plugins.MonacaBackend" .But Monaca back-end is working. I am not getting why only this plugin not adding in the debugger.Kindly please let me know here.

Answer (score 0):

That is just the behavior of the default debugger app.  To have that go away, you need to use the Custom Build Debugger.  More information can be found here: http://docs.monaca.mobi/cur/en/manual/debugger/installation/debugger_android/#custom-debugger-and

Long and the short of it though, it adds all the plugins you have associated to your project.

Answer (score 0):

That's actually a UI bug. mobi.monaca.plugins.MonacaBackend will never be included in the custom debugger but the debugger should not display it's missing. We will fix this soon.